# How to record Zoom H4 and guitar at the same time

Tags: ableton-live

I'm recording guitar lessons and I want to record both my guitar and voice at the same time. 
To do so, I need two audio tracks in Live. But the difficult part is that to get my voice from the Zoom h4, I use the USB cable plugged on my computer and I connect the Zoom to my PC with I/O option. But to make it an audio input for live, I can't choose both Scarlett 2i2 AND Zoom H4 USB devices at the same time.

I tried to plug my Zoom H4 directly on my scarlett 2i2 interface but no signal was detected. I don't know if it's possible.

What can I do to fix this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How does the Zoom come into this?   Connect your guitar to one channel of the 2i2, a microphone to the other.

Comment: I tried to plug the Zoom directly in the second input of my scarlett but when I do so, I have no signal detected...

Comment: Are you using the headphone output of the Zoom into a channel of the 2i2?  That should work, as long as you have made up a suitable cable, considering that the Zoom output is stereo and there is only a mono input available on the 2i2, the other one being used by the guitar.

Comment: I did not tried the headphone output of the zoom. For now, I used the jack connection. I'll try what you say...And if it doesn't work, maybe I'll just invest in a true USB microphone. Merry christmas.

Comment: Your Zoom IS a USB microphone.  If you want to use the 2i2 you need a normal, non-USB microphone.   You might be able to coax the Zoom into acting as such, by tapping its monitor output.  But it's a complicated way of doing a simple job.